# How to find out which branch FETCH_HEAD is on

Tags: git

In git, how can I find out which branch FETCH_HEAD is on? And how can I switch my repository to it?

I did a 'repo sync', but I don't see a commit I am expecting. 
So I use eclipse git tool to open my git repository. I see that commit with a label FETCH_HEAD.

My question is how can I find out what branch is FETCH_HEAD is on, so that I can switch to thab branch.

I thought I create a local branch which tracks a remote branch. I am not sure why that is not working.

Thank you.

Comment: There should be a file named `FETCH_HEAD` in the `.git` folder.

Answer (score 4):

`FETCH_HEAD` points to where the remote branch tracked by the local branch has advanced: The tip of the remote branch specified by `branch.<BRANCH_NAME>.merge` (see `.git/FETCH_HEAD` or the setting `[branch "<BRANCH_NAME>"] merge` in `.git/config`).

So if you are on `master` and you `git fetch`, and `branch.master.merge` points to `refs/heads/master`, then `FETCH_HEAD` will get the same value as `origin/master`.